# Find the maximum number in a list using lambda function, without max(),sort(),sorted() , and 'in' keyword in python3

Tags: python-3.x

And not import other modules except sys
what I've tried, occurs an error: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

```
A = [-1, 3, 7, 99, 0]
print(map(A, lambda x, y: x if x >= y else y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lambda` to make a recursive function:

```
f = lambda l: l[0] if len(l) == 1 else l[0] if l[0] > f(l[1:]) else f(l[1:])
```

so that:

```
f(A)
```

returns:

```
99
```

Comment: That's fantastic, other question is if I change the '>' to '<' in this function, this not return the minimum value, I wonder how to use similar way to let it return minimum value ?

Comment: Changing `>` to `<` does make the function return the minimum value instead. See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/PricklyOutstandingWebpages

Answer (score 2):

You're close. `map` only changes individual elements to other individual elements. To form a result based on all the elements, you need to use `reduce` instead:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x if x >= y else y, A))
99
```

(Also, the reason for the error you got was that your argument order was wrong. It's supposed to be the function and then the iterable.)

Comment: I wonder if not import other modules, how to do that ? without 'in' keyword and those built-in function mentioned above.

Comment: @Eric Just look how reduce itself does it: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/24dc2f8c56697f9ee51a4887cf0814b6600c1815/Lib/functools.py#L225-L256

Comment: @JosephSible The implementation of `reduce` does use the `in` keyword.

Comment: @blhsing Whoops, so it does.

Answer (score 1):

And here's an iterative approach, which filters the list with a `lambda` function that returns `True` if the current value is greater than all the other values by mapping all the list values to a `lambda` function that returns `True` if the current value is greater than or equal to the other value:

```
next(filter(lambda i: all(map(lambda j: i >= j, A)), A))
```

This returns:

```
99
```